# Force lowercase - ios swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I would like to force lowercase in an `UITextfield` when the user is typing. 
I came out so far with this code, but seems like it's not lowering characters.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }

    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string.lowercaseString)

    switch textField {
    // Allow only lower-case vowels in this field,
    // and limit its contents to a maximum of 6 characters.
    case userNameTextField:
        return prospectiveText.characters.count <= 27
    default:
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you should set following property on your textfield to restrict auto capitalisation:

```
textfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
```

And this is how you can restrict it further:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet()) {
        // Do not allow upper case letters
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

**UPDATED FOR SWIFT 4**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) {
        // Do not allow upper case letters
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: thank you ! I have a question for you how we can avoid the "Space" in keyboard to don't allowed the user tapped ?

Comment: I believe you want to restrict only initial space to enter by user ... like starting character. This can easily be restricted by returning `false` in above method for `if string == " "`.

Comment: let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
        let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespaceSet)
        if let _ = range {
            return false
        }
 better one ;)

Comment: That is if you do not want space anywhere in your string. I thought you want to restrict only first one :). Anyway, glad I could be helpful. Cheers :)!

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this and lowercase the entire string when something has changed.

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: "textViewChanged", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged);


  func textViewChanged(){
        textfield.text = textfield.text?.lowercaseString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for swift 3 users, the above code given by Abhinav is just converted to the following

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from:NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) {

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert all input characters to lower case you should do this code:

**Swift 4:**

in `override func viewDidLoad()` add this:

```
 textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

and then add this function to your class:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text:String = textfield.text {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textfield.text = text.lowercased()
            }
        }

}
```

it is necessary to change it in main thread.

Comment: touch events are already handled in main thread. No need to Dispatch