# How do i get the keyboard to start with a lowercase letter?

Tags: swift

When I press the text field screen, the uppercase keyboard appears. But I want it to start with a lowercase letter and then continue as desired. I don't want only lower case or only upper case input

When I click on the text field screen, capital letters appear directly like this.

```
searchField.autocapitalizationType = .none
```

I tried but it keeps on starting with a capital letter. Also, in the only answer I found, I found a code that only allows lowercase letters.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195946/force-lowercase-ios-swift)

[image: 1]

Comment: That is so bizarre!  I just tried the exact same code as you had and it worked for me (started with a lowercase keyboard).  I set up a search bar in `Main.storyboard`, connected it to an `@IBOutlet` named `searchBar` in `ViewController`, and put `searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none` inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Where did you put the line `searchField.autocapitalizationType = .none`?  Was it inside `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else?